# Passing object as parameter to constructor function and copy its properties to the new object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, constructor

I have a JavaScript constructor like this:

```
function Box(obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
}
```

which i want to pass an object as a parameter like this:

```
var box = new Box({prop1: "a", prop2: "b", prop3: "c"})
```

and gives me something like this:

```
box.obj.prop1
box.obj.prop2
box.obj.prop3
```

but I would like the properties to be directly on the object like this:

```
box.prop1
box.prop2
box.prop3
```

I know I could do something like this:

```
function Box(obj) {
    this.prop1 = obj.prop1;
    this.prop2 = obj.prop2;
    this.prop3 = obj.prop3;
}
```

But that is not good because then my constructor would have to "know" before the names of the properties of the object parameter. What I would like is to be able to pass different objects as parameters and assign their properties directly as properties of the new custom object created by the constructor so I get `box.propX` and not `box.obj.propX`. Hope I am making myself clear, maybe I am measing something very obvious but I am a newbie so please need your help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe use prototype?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could do this. There is probably also a jquery way...

```
function Box(obj) {
  for (var fld in obj) {
    this[fld] = obj[fld];
  }
}
```

You can include a test for hasOwnProperty if you've (I think foolishly) extended object

```
function Box(obj) {
   for (var fld in obj) {
     if (obj.hasOwnProperty(fld)) {
       this[fld] = obj[fld];
     }
   }
 }
```

**Edit**

Ah, ha! it's `jQuery.extend`

So, the jQuery way is:

```
function Box(obj) {
  $.extend(this, obj);
}
```

Comment: One thing to note neither solution is doing a _deep copy_.  Depending on your _actual_ implementation there is potential for problems.  For example if instead of passing your object anonymously you create a variable `obj={ prop1:..., propDanger: { a:1, b:2 } }` and pass that to your constructor `var box = new Box(obj)`, then later edits to `obj.propDanger.a` will also change `box.propDanger.a`.

Comment: @Brett Good point. Rarely a problem, but a good think to know so you don't get surprised by it when it does happen.

Answer (score 9):

Simply put this in your constructor

```
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      this[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
  }
```

Comment: I am giving the accepted answer to @Hemlock because he got it first, but thanks really!

Answer (score 7):

Really short

```
function Box(obj) {
  Object.assign(this, obj);
}
```

Comment: way better than doing `this[prop] = obj[prop]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example with the javascript module pattern:

```
var s,
NewsWidget = {

  settings: {
    numArticles: 5,
    articleList: $("#article-list"),
    moreButton: $("#more-button")
  },

  init: function(options) {
    this.settings = $.extend(this.settings, options);
    s = this.settings;
    this.bindUIActions();
  },

  bindUIActions: function() {
    s.moreButton.on("click", function() {
      NewsWidget.getMoreArticles(s.numArticles);
    });
  },

  getMoreArticles: function(numToGet) {
    // $.ajax or something
    // using numToGet as param
  }

};

$(function(){
  NewsWidget.init({
    numArticles: 6
  });

  console.log(s.numArticles);
});
```